# Unable to render a Django view function from React js forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

We usually use Jinja tags to submit forms through Django Templates i.e `{% url 'view_name' %}`
but this does not work in React.This gaves syntax error and hence i tried as below. But this too does'nt work.
React Js Code -

```
<form onSubmit = 'form_submit' method = "post">
                   <DjangoCSRFToken/>
                   <input type = "text" placeholder = "Email" name = "email"></input><br/>
                   <input type = "password" placeholder = "Password" name = "password"></input><br/>
                   <input type = "password" placeholder = "Confirm Password" name = "password1"></input>
                   <input type = "submit"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this doesn't work because the architecture should be different. You should use something like [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/) or the [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to create a REST API and connect the front-end to the back-end. Your question is in a hazy instance.

Comment: Would you please explain me this in much detail

Comment: Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZgRbnIsgrA&t=492s) video series. It helps a lot but may take a while to understand it deeply and completely.